# Problema com Boostrap limpar campo FileInput

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma página com 2 **input text** e 2 **input file**
Quando eu recebo a resposta do ajax, mando limpar todo o formulário conforme código abaixo, porém somente um campo não é limpo o campo:

```
<input class="fileUploadAudio" id="fileUploadAudio" name="fileUploadAudio" type="file"></span>
```

Acredito que deve ter algum conflito, já fiz de tudo e não consigo limpar esse bendito campo.

[**Segue a pagina**](http://williamvillar.com.br/Push_Novo/msg_big_pic.php)

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Imagem para Push</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                       <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                          <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                             <img src="http://placehold.it/190x140/7761A7/ffffff" alt="...">
                          </div>
                          <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"></div>
                          <div>
                             <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Selecionar imagem</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Alterar</span>
                             <input class="arquivo" id="arquivo" name="arquivo" type="file"></span>
                             <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remover</a>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Áudio para a campanha</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                       <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                          <input name="..." value="" type="hidden">
                          <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Selecionar áudio</span>
                          <span class="fileinput-exists">Alterar</span>
                          <input class="fileUploadAudio" id="fileUploadAudio" name="fileUploadAudio" type="file"></span>
                          <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
                          <a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput" style="float: none">×</a>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

No retorno do ajax eu mando limpar os campos do formulário dessa forma:

```
$(".formulario")[0].reset();
$(".formulario").get(0).reset();
$('#cancelButton').hide();
$("#fileUploadAudio").val("");
$('#submitButton').hide();
```

Já até tentei limpar somente o fileinput dessa forma:

```
$('#fileUploadAudio').val('');
```

Comment: Tem como criar um [*fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/) para demonstrar o problema?

Comment: tem certeza que esse input ta dentro do form? as vezes falta fechar uma tag ai zoa tudo.

Comment: O console apresenta algum erro quando tenta limpar o input?

Comment: Pessoal, acabei de subir a pagina se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço. segue o link - > http://williamvillar.com.br/Push_Novo/msg_big_pic.php

Comment: Pessoal, acabei de colocar um botão chamado CLEAR.
Para testar fazem a seguinte mandeira: selecione 2 arquivos nos 2 fileinput depois cliquem nesse botão.  ->> http://williamvillar.com.br/Push_Novo/msg_big_pic.php